# Null check with ?. vs ?: fails in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have following statement in my code:

```
safeOrderResult.accomplished?.let{ safeAccomplished->
  //Do something with safeAccomplished when accomplished <> null

  Log.i(TAG,"bind: safeOrderResult.accomplishedId.let?{}") 
}?:let{

  //Do something when accomplished == null

  Log.i(TAG,"bind: safeOrderResult.accomplishedId?:let{} *null*" )
}
```

Here my code does something strange:

On a Samsung TAB A (i think not significant) it works as expected.

On a Samsung S9 it calls both let sections.

Snippet from Logcat Samsung S9 (android 10)

```
2021-05-06 14:11:35.427 9069-9069/no.norva24.mslam I/ViewHolder: bind: safeOrderResult.accomplishedId = 408
2021-05-06 14:11:35.427 9069-9069/no.norva24.mslam I/ViewHolder: bind: safeOrderResult.accomplishedId.let?.{}
2021-05-06 14:11:35.427 9069-9069/no.norva24.mslam I/ViewHolder: bind: handleDate = null <- inside above let: ok 
2021-05-06 14:11:35.427 9069-9069/no.norva24.mslam I/ViewHolder: bind: safeOrderResult.accomplishedId?:let{} *null*
2021-05-06 14:11:35.427 9069-9069/no.norva24.mslam I/ViewHolder: bind: flagged = false or null
```

TabA: android 10

```
2021-05-06 14:21:16.676 2468-2468/no.norva24.mslam I/ViewHolder: bind: safeOrderResult.accomplishedId = 427
2021-05-06 14:21:16.676 2468-2468/no.norva24.mslam I/ViewHolder: bind: safeOrderResult.accomplishedId.let?.{}
2021-05-06 14:21:16.678 2468-2468/no.norva24.mslam I/ViewHolder: bind: handleDate = null <-- inside above let
2021-05-06 14:21:16.685 2468-2468/no.norva24.mslam I/ViewHolder: bind: flagged = false or null
```

The key point is, how can a value both be null and contain a value?, or can kotlin "change" to null and kick in in the second "null" let, if value has changed in the first first let (which I didn't do)

I am Using kotlin 1.5.0

**EDIT 2021.05.06 18:55 GMT+2**

I am not sure, but I might have learned something here today: ;)

```
safeOrderResult.accomplished?.let{ safeAccomplished->

  //Do something with safeAccomplished when accomplished <> null

  /*Here I have preserved my value in safeAccomplished
    And actually returning a value below (a Unit()) from Log.i ?*/
  Log.i(TAG,"bind: safeOrderResult.accomplishedId.let?{}") 
}?:let{
   
  //Do something when accomplished == null

  /* But why did the code kick in here ?
     After it was inside the let above ? I thought the '?:let' was 
     continuing if the '?.let' didn't kick in. 
     */
  Log.i(TAG,"bind: safeOrderResult.accomplishedId?:let{} *null*" )
}

/*
Below is the actual code which had the trouble (the code isn't finished therefore the "preserved" `let` values isn't used)
*/

                        safeOrderResult.accomplishedId?.let {
                            listItemOrderListLinearLayoutCompatStatus.apply {
                                visibility = View.VISIBLE
                                listItemOrderListMaterialTextViewOrderStatus.text =
                                    context.resources.getStringArray(
                                        R.array.basic_register_accomplish_status_names)[1]
                                listItemOrderListMaterialTextViewDate.text =
                                    dateStringSplitSpace(safeOrderResult.registeredDate)
                                Log.i(TAG, "bind: handleDate = ${safeOrderResult.handleDate}")
                                listItemOrderListMaterialTextViewReason.text =
                                    if(safeOrderResult.handleDate.isNullOrEmpty())
                                        "Still possible to update"
                                    else
                                        "Assignment locked on ${dateStringSplitSpace(safeOrderResult.handleDate)}"
                                setBackgroundColor(
                                    ContextCompat.getColor(
                                        itemView.context,
                                        if(safeOrderResult.handleDate.isNullOrEmpty())
                                            R.color.list_item_register_field_accomplished_background
                                        else
                                            R.color.list_item_register_field_accomplished_locked_background
                                    )
                                )

                            }
                            listItemOrderListLinearLayoutCompatStatusMore?.apply {
                                setBackgroundColor(
                                    ContextCompat.getColor(
                                        itemView.context,
                                        if(safeOrderResult.handleDate.isNullOrEmpty())
                                            R.color.list_item_register_field_accomplished_background
                                        else
                                            R.color.list_item_register_field_accomplished_locked_background
                                    )
                                )
                            }
                        }?:let {
                            safeOrderResult.passedId?.let { safePassedId->
                                listItemOrderListLinearLayoutCompatStatus.apply {
                                    visibility = View.VISIBLE
                                    listItemOrderListMaterialTextViewOrderStatus.text =
                                        context.resources.getStringArray(
                                            R.array.basic_register_accomplish_status_names
                                        )[2]
                                    listItemOrderListMaterialTextViewDate.text =
                                        dateStringSplitSpace(safeOrderResult.registeredDate)
                                    listItemOrderListMaterialTextViewReason.text =
                                        safeOrderResult.passedReason
                                    setBackgroundColor(
                                        ContextCompat.getColor(
                                            itemView.context,
                                            R.color.list_item_register_field_passed_background,
                                        )
                                    )
                                }
                            }?:let {
                                listItemOrderListLinearLayoutCompatStatus.apply {
                                    visibility = View.GONE
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

** ADDENDUM 2020.05.06 19:30 GMT+2 **

In playground I got trouble with this:

```
/**
 * You can edit, run, and share this code. 
 * play.kotlinlang.org 
 */

class A {
    fun f() {
        let { println(it) }
    }
}

data class DataClass(
    var value1:String?=null,
    var value2:String?=null
)

fun main() {
    A().f()
    
    var myData = DataClass()
    
    myData.value1 = "1"
    
    
    myData.value1?.let{ safeValue1->
        println("value1 = "+safeValue1)
    }?:let{
        println("value1==null !!")
    }
    
    myData.value2?.let{ safeValue2->
        println("value2 = "+safeValue2)
    }?:let{
        println("value2==null !!")
    }   
    
    
}
```

Where it kicked on the `?:let`'s above. This was ok in kotin v.1.5.0 at least...

**ADDENDUM 2: 2020.05.06 19:40 GMT+2**

[image]

So... `dataClass.value?:let{ }` isn't allowed ? in a 'standard' kotlin scenario to check for null existence ?, but still 'valid' in `AS2020.3.1.15 w/kotlin 1.5.0` ...

**ADDENDUM 3: 2020.05.06 19:55 GMT+2**

When using another approach (omitting `let` keyword in `?:let{` I got this answer to the based on the playground code above:

[image]

Here I expected also the value2 to show up with `value2==null !!` but it didn`t...

Here's the playground code now:

```
/**
 * You can edit, run, and share this code. 
 * play.kotlinlang.org 
 */

class A {
    fun f() {
        let { println(it) }
    }
}

data class DataClass(
    var value1:String?=null,
    var value2:String?=null
)

fun main() {
    A().f()
    
    var myData = DataClass()
    
    myData.value1 = "1"
    
    /*
    myData.value1?.let{ safeValue1->
        println("value1 = "+safeValue1)
    }?:let{
        println("value1==null !!")
    }
    
    myData.value2?.let{ safeValue2->
        println("value2 = "+safeValue2)
    }?:let{
        println("value2==null !!")
    }   
    */
    
    myData.value1?.let{ safeValue1->
        println("value1 = "+safeValue1)
    }
    
    myData.value1?:{
        println("value1==null !!")
    }
    
    myData.value2?.let{ safeValue2->
        println("value2 = "+safeValue2)
    }
    
    myData.value2?:{
        println("value2==null !!")
    }
    
}
```

...still a *little* confused ...

Comment: The code `?:let` does not compile for me. And if you use `?.` twice it will just run both blocks if `accomplished <> null`

Comment: no, `variable?.let{ safeVariable-> 'code'  }?:let{ 'code' }` should work, and I have used it "everywhere", but the funny thing is suddenly behaves different in this scenario (with different devices.

Comment: Can you post a minimal example on Kotlin playground? `?: let` looks up a function `let` globally, not on an object, so this shouldn't be defined or call a different `let` function you defined.

Comment: Why is everyone saying you can't call `let` this way? It's called on `this` as the implicit receiver. Minimal example: https://pl.kotl.in/bCB7WTOYn

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I played around a little bit and landed with this: https://pl.kotl.in/kSCj9kKjf where the "code check" kicked on the secondary `?:let`, that's strange AS2020.3.1.15 didn't kicked on..., see addendum in the Q above.

Comment: 1. You can't use `let` like this _in a top-level function_ because there's no `this` to be the receiver.

Comment: 2. `listItemOrderListLinearLayoutCompatStatusMore?.apply { ... }` of course can return `null` and then as cactustictacs's and Tenfour04's answers explain, the whole `?.let { ... }` will return null and the right-hand side of `:?` is executed.

Comment: 3. `myData.value2 ?: { ... }` evaluates to `{ ... }` (which is a lambda) and then you ignore the result, without calling that lambda. 4. `let` is very much not a keyword in Kotlin, it's a perfectly normal function.

Comment: ...@AlexeyRomanov you're right... but it 'feels' like a keyword...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to bind `accomplished` to a variable as in @Tenfour04's answer, I'd write it as

```
safeOrderResult.accomplished.let {
    if (it != null) {
        // safeOrderResult.accomplished was not null, use it
    } else {
        // safeOrderResult.accomplished was null
    }
}
```

or

```
safeOrderResult.accomplished.let { accomplished ->
    if (accomplished != null) {
        // safeOrderResult.accomplished was not null, use accomplished
    } else {
        // safeOrderResult.accomplished was null
    }
}
```

Note `.let` and not `?.let`. But pick on readability/convenience. I definitely wouldn't use

```
value?.let{ safeValue-> /*dowork*/}; value?:let{/*do null work*/}
```

as you suggest in another comment.

Comment: No, of course not, but I couldn't breakt the lines in a comment here... i comment it in two lines below.

Comment: `value?.let{safeValue-> /*doWork when not null*/}`

Comment: `value?:let{ /*doWork when value null*/}`

Comment: Anyway, I think you are right, I'll go for your approach, because you can come along situation where the value might change in between when you use a normal `if` sentence, but when you use `let` (or `also`) you "preserve" the value in that `let` scope.

Comment: BTW: I Have updated my Q to show the actual code snippet which contains theese `?.let` and `?:let` parts which behaves 'somehow' 'erratic'

Answer (score 2):

The `let` function can indeed change your target to null. It changes the target to whatever it returns. A lambda implicitly returns the result of its last expression. Your code above has a `Log.i()` call as its last expression, so it returns Unit, so the second `let` function should never run if the first one does. Is it possible you've snipped off some code at the end of your first `let` lambda that could possibly return a null value?

A quick fix for the above problem would be to swap `let` for `also`, because `also` always returns its receiver.

I think most experienced Kotlin users will advise you not to chain scope function calls like this because it makes the code hard to follow and it is easy to introduce subtle bugs. You can write a more robust version like this:

```
val accomplished = safeOrderResult.accomplished
if (accomplished != null) {
    //Do something with smart-cast non-nullable accomplished
} else {
    //Do something when accomplished == null
}
```

Comment: I have added som more info in the Q, it is quite interesting though even playground gives me some arbitrary code fails... and doesn't quite work as 'I expect'...

Comment: @RoarGrønmo I see your error in your edited code. The last expression in your first `let` lambda starts with the null-safe call `listItemOrderListLinearLayoutCompatStatusMore?.apply {`, so the `let` function will return null if `listItemOrderListLinearLayoutCompatStatusMore` is null, and so the second `let` function will be triggered by the Elvis operator. This sort of subtle bug is why you shouldn't chain scope functions.

Comment: Thanx, for mentioning that, I've learned something today, and need to do some 'sublte' codewashing and use `if` (even if I rather don't want to...)

Answer (score 2):

At a guess, the first one is returning `null` at the end, which means the value produced by that whole expression is `null`, so the stuff after the `?:` is triggered (since that's an "if the left side evaluates to null" condition).

Why that would only happen on some Samsung models - who knows, they have a history of messing with things in the Android library! I'd check exactly what's going on in the block and what it might evaluate to. You might need to return `Unit` at the end, or use a function like `apply` that returns the receiver instead of the result of the lambda.

This is why the `if/else` is a better fit - you have a condition at the start, and you decide whether to do one thing or another, exclusively. `let` produces a value, and it's often used to propagate a value down a chain, and return a result. `?:` is a final default value, for if that result turns out to be null.

It's absolutely possible to run the `let` block **and** the code after the `?:`, and sometimes that a thing you want to do. As a construction it's often used for returning a default value. So `if/else` is a little more explicit about what you're doing and how it's *meant* to work, and it helps avoid surprise bugs like this one!

Comment: "You don't have a value after the ?:, you're not calling let on anything." It should be called on `this` by default, no?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov ah dammit you're right, I don't know what I was thinking. I'll edit that, sorry Roar!

Answer (score 1):

You *can* do an if-null-else with `?.let` but it's not very readable in my opinion

```kotlin
var s: String? = "Str"
s?.let { println("A ok") } ?: run { println("A null") }
s = null
s?.let { println("B ok") } ?: run { println("B null") }
```

```
A ok
B null
```

It is also possible to introduce subtle bugs like this:

```kotlin
var s: String? = "Str"
s?.let { println("A ok"); null } ?: run { println("A null") }
```

```
A ok
A null
```

This is why **you should use an if-else** if you both need the non-null and null case. (`?.` is intended for the case where only the non-null case makes sense):

```kotlin
if (s == null) println("A null") else println("A ok")
```

```kotlin
if (s == null) { 
    println("A null") 
} else { 
    println("A ok") 
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the result is different in different devices, that I don't like.

Comment: Try the if-else and see if it's still different

Comment: BTW: Is `value?.let{ safeValue-> /*dowork*/}; value?:let{/*do null work*/}` a better approach ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanx for many good answers above, and you all are right...

I landed on following solution for my problem, but still not quite happy though:

I use `.apply` to remove some `value.` overhead,

```
safeOrderResult.apply{

   if(accomplished!=null){
        //Do something with accomplished since accomplished <> null

        Log.i(TAG,"bind: accomplished != null") 
   }else{

        //Do something when accomplished == null

        Log.i(TAG,"bind: accomplished == null" )
   }
}
```

I mark accepted for @Alexey Romanov suggestion which is quite reasonable.